# colaboratoryの起動時に「ログインしてください」となり、そこから進まない

Tags: google-colaboratory

初めて利用させていただきます、よろしくお願いします。

G-suite for educationのアカウントでのことです。

google colaboratoryを管理コンソールより、許可アプリとして登録しました。
※念のため、G-suite marketと、管理コンソールのデバイス→Chrome管理→アプリと拡張機能のところそれぞれにアプリcolaboratoryを追加しています。

管理コンソールで、アプリ→G-suiteコア→googleドライブ→機能とアプリケーション→ドライブSDKを「オン」としました。

続いて、G-suiteのアカウント(生徒・教員)のGoogleドライブにアプリの追加でcolaboratoryを追加しました。
ホワイトリスト登録してあるため、インストールは無事にできています。

ここまでで手順が足りないのか、googleドライブ上で新規のcolaboratoryファイルを作ろうとすると、「Googleへのログインが必要　　続行するには、googleアカウントにログインしている必要があります。」と出て、「OK」しかボタンがなく、ファイルを作ることができなくなってしまいます。OKと押すとリダイレクトされて、まだログインしてくださいのメッセージが出ます。これの繰り返しです。

ちなみに、管理コンソールでは、プロキシの除外設定として、「colab.research.google.com」を指定しています。

使用ブラウザはfirefox、Chromeともにダメでした。

不思議なのは、同じ端末でアカウントを個人のgmailでログインして、同様にcolaboratoryを試すと普通にプログラム入力画面に進むのです。管理コンソールの設定な気がしていますが、何を設定見直せばいいのか検討がつかず質問させていただきました。

どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 解決できました。

Comment: 同じ問題にハマっており、どうやって解決したか教えていただきたいです。

Comment: @user40588 さん、もしお時間ありましたら[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)いただけると嬉しいです。暫く待つと自分の回答を承認することもできるようになります。

Answer (score 0):

同じ問題を抱えていましたが、解決することができました。
G Suite for educationの管理者アカウントでログインし、google adminにアクセス、管理コンソールを立ち上げます。管理コンソールのホームページから、[アプリ] 次に [その他の Google サービス] にアクセスします。
ページ上部のメッセージにある [変更] をクリックします。
そこにあるgoogleサービスへのアクセスをオンにすれば使用できるようになりました。