# Google colaboratoryにログインできない

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratory を久々に使おうと思ったのですが、ログインできません。

試したことは

- ファイル => 「ノートブックを新規作成」
- 前に作ったノートブックをGoogle Driveから開く

という2つです。
どちらとも

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

というポップアップが出てしまいます（すでにログインは済んでいます）。
このポップアップの「OK」を押してもまたこのポップアップの画面にリダイレクトされます。
またこの画面では「OK」以外にクリックできるところはありません。

以前までは普通にGoogle Colaboratoryが使えたのに、久々に開こうとすると使えなくなっていました。

またアカウントはG-Suiteで管理されているアカウントです。管理者権限においてアプリのアクセスを確認してもユーザーはColabを使えるようになっているようです。

なにか知っている方いたら教えて欲しいです。

Comment: 関連……？: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67526/19110 (未解決ですが最近の質問です)

Comment: 当てずっぽうですが、ブラウザの設定またはブラウザのアドオン等で 3rd Party Cookies がブロックされたりしていないでしょうか？ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582239

Comment: ここにある方法で3rd Party Cookies に許可しましたがダメでした。